# GitlabCI - Package Registry - NPM Package can't publish

Tags: npm, package, gitlab-ci

My goal is to publish a npm package (private if possible) on the Gitlab Registry.

Here is my files :

**Package.json :**

```
{
    "name": "@sushislasher/sushislasher-package",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Package for game",
    "main": "index.ts",
    "repository": "https://gitlab.com/sushislasher/sushislasher-package",
    "author": "Gildraen",
    "license": "MIT",
    "private": false
}
```

**Gitlab-CI.yml :**

```
stages:
  - deploy

image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/docker-in-docker
services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  COMPOSE_FILE: "docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.gitlab-ci.yml"

.template-load-gitlab-image: &internal-image
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER -p $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker-compose pull js || true

deploy:
  <<: *internal-image
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - |
      {
        echo "@${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}:registry=${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/"
    echo "${CI_API_V4_URL#https?}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"
  } | tee -a app/.npmrc

    - make install
    - make npm-publish
```

make install build container, up them and do a yarn install.
make npm publish do basically a npm publish.
All in container.
I'm using node:15.7-alpine

But for now, despite all my tries and research, can't make this work, i have this error :

```
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-03T11_51_48_233Z-debug.log
1
```

I try to follow gitlab doc.. but i'm kind of stuck right now.. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do it. With a lot of try and try, here are the key points.

- Package name. It is very important to keep an eye on it. What the documentation does not say it's that the "package.json" need the same name as the registry.
  If your registry is @foo, your registry need @foo/something as project name. With the code I provide in the script, it takes the root project, and this is the registry.

For me it's https://gitlab.com/gildraen/sushislasher-package
so my package.json name is @gildraen/sushislasher-package (though the name seems not important)

So I did it all over again from scratch, with paying more attention to this, and it worked.
I really think this was my real mistake: the registry name.